# mysql :query max date group by 2 columns wrong result

Tags: mysql

I have this table on my database

**EXAMPLE DATA****

**(tablename = sections_content)**

```
section_name   |  report_text|countryname|policyname     |statecode| datepublished | dateupdated**
Executive Summary|...........|Algeria    |WEEE           |DZ       | 2016-05-11    |2017-02-16 
Executive Summary|...........|Algeria    |WEEE           |DZ       | 2017-02-15    |2017-02-16
Executive Summary|...........|Algeria    |Batteries      |DZ       | 2017-02-15    |2017-02-16
Executive Summary|...........|Algeria    |Packaging      |DZ       | 2017-02-15    |2017-02-16
Executive Summary|...........|South Africa|Packaging     |DZ       | 2017-02-15    |2017-02-16
```

and I want to find max datepublished for each statecode column and policyname column

like the result should have only one record which is max datepublished per country/policy

So one country should have 3 records for 3 policies (WEEE/Batteries/Packaging) like

```
Executive Summary|...........|Algeria   |WEEE           |DZ       |2017-02-15     |2017-02-16
Executive Summary|...........|Algeria   |Batteries      |DZ       |2017-02-15     |2017-02-16
Executive Summary|...........|Algeria   |Packaging      |DZ       |2017-02-15     |2017-02-16
```

The mysql code I'm using is

```
SELECT  t.section_name,
        t.report_text,
        t.countryname,
        t.policyname,
        t.statecode,
        t.datepublished,
        date_format(t.dateupdated,"%Y-%m-%d")as dateupdated

FROM sections_content t

INNER JOIN (
            select max(datepublished) as Maxdate,statecode,policyname
            from sections_content
            group by statecode,policyname
            ) tm

            ON t.datepublished= tm.Maxdate and t.statecode = tm.statecode and t.policyname=tm.policyname

WHERE t.section_name="Executive Summary"
```

but the result is wrong,some countries not pick all policies

such as South Africa country pick only Batteries and Packaging but WEEE is missing(but there's WEEE for South Africa on the database)

So I would like to ask anyone to check what's wrong with my code.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks good to me. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: report_text is not a column in the data set provided. And South Africa isn't a value in the data set provided.

Comment: @Strawberry table above is just example data but the real data has all

Comment: Obviously, we can only comment on the information actually provided.

Comment: @Strawberry alright,I edited already but there are like hundred countries in the table that I can't provide it all.Anyway, thanks for helping.

Comment: If you want to include all countries, then you have to include countryname in the subquery SELECT and GROUP BY, and the JOIN

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you made a too complex query for a simple problem, you already had the answer in your query:

Just try it this way:

```
SELECT  policyname,
        statecode,
        max(datepublished)
FROM sections_content
WHERE section_name="Executive Summary"
group by statecode,policyname
```

Comment: I can see no merit in reprinting the OP's subquery.

Comment: Maybe has no merit just because it's the right query, and there's no need to make a complex answer for an easy issue

Comment: The OP wants to return all related columns from the table.

Comment: @curiousp If this answers the question, then the question is very misleading!

Comment: @Strawberry Hey I'm really appreciated your help,I'm sorry if I made you misunderstanding.It's my bad,don't be angry. please,I upvoted your answer for being kind to help.

Comment: @curiousp I'm not angry. Merely perplexed.

Comment: @nacho I just added another column(id column) and found that this query took id wrong SELECT  id,policyname,
        statecode,
        max(datepublished)
FROM sections_content
WHERE section_name="Executive Summary"
group by statecode,policyname

Comment: @curiousp That's right because if you are grouping by statecode and policyname, you can have a lot of diferent id for the same statecode. You shouldn't use a UNIQUE column with a group by clause

Comment: @nacho So how should I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sections_content;

CREATE TABLE sections_content
(Section_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,countryname  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
,policyname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,statecode CHAR(2) NOT NULL
,datepublished DATE NOT NULL
,dateupdated DATE NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(countryname,policyname,statecode,datepublished) -- assumed PK
);

INSERT INTO sections_content VALUES
('Executive Summary','Algeria','WEEE','DZ','2016-05-11','2017-02-16'),
('Executive Summary','Algeria','WEEE','DZ','2017-02-15','2017-02-16'),
('Executive Summary','Algeria','Batteries','DZ','2017-02-15','2017-02-16'),
('Executive Summary','Algeria','Packaging','DZ','2017-02-15','2017-02-16'),
('Executive Summary','South Africa','Packaging','DZ','2017-02-15','2017-02-16');

SELECT t.*
  FROM sections_content t
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(datepublished) Maxdate
            , statecode
            , policyname
            , countryname
         FROM sections_content
        GROUP 
           BY statecode
            , policyname
            , countryname
     ) tm
    ON t.datepublished = tm.Maxdate 
   AND t.statecode = tm.statecode 
   AND t.policyname = tm.policyname
   AND t.countryname = tm.countryname
 WHERE t.section_name = "Executive Summary";

 +-------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
 | Section_name      | countryname  | policyname | statecode | datepublished | dateupdated |
 +-------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
 | Executive Summary | Algeria      | Batteries  | DZ        | 2017-02-15    | 2017-02-16  |
 | Executive Summary | Algeria      | Packaging  | DZ        | 2017-02-15    | 2017-02-16  |
 | Executive Summary | South Africa | Packaging  | DZ        | 2017-02-15    | 2017-02-16  |
 | Executive Summary | Algeria      | WEEE       | DZ        | 2017-02-15    | 2017-02-16  |
 +-------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
```